# Mocking Internal State

Tags: java, mocking

I'm looking for a suitable mocking tool to mock internal states (e.g. void methods).  I know Powermock and JMock can do this but I have not made a choice yet.  I have more experience with EasyMock but have not tried mocking internal states.  I'm not so sure if it is inherently supported.  I'm still scouring its documentation.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "internal states" - you've mentioned void methods, which are easily handled by EasyMock, but not what you really mean by internal states.

Comment: Also check out Mockito http://mockito.org - it has some nice features

Comment: Some void methods do a lot of things inside where the state after the invocation cannot be easily captured. In Powermock for example, there are methods like setInternalState, getInternalState that allows you to simply mock the internal state.  I hope this clarifies the question a bit

Comment: I think this also falls under the "partial mocking" category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By internal state, i assume you might be meaning some private or package-private method that your public method calls in order to do its job.  In my view, if your internally-called method is so complicated that you want to mock it out, then you should really pull it out into it's own class, test that class separately, and then inject it as a service to the original class you wanted to test as a service.

So your class looks something like this and you want to test `someMethod`.

```
public class Original {
    public void someMethod() {
        // ... stuff
        Object someValue = callComplicatedPrivateMethod();
        // ... more stuff
    }
}
```

I would change it to this:

```
public class Original {
    private ComplicatedService service;

    public Original(ComplicatedService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        // ... stuff
        Object someValue = service.callComplicatedMethod();
        // ... more stuff
    }
}
```

Now you can easily (normally) mock `ComplicatedService` and test your `Original` class as normal.

Comment: thank you for your reply. In principle, you are absolutely right. But I am working on a legacy application and I have to deal with shotgun surgery. At this point, I think PowerMock is very appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a class like this where you've got an annoying bit of internal state (which is access by a method called `doSomething`) and it's stopping you testing `myMethod`.

```
public class Me {
     public int myMethod () {
         doSomething();
         return 7;
     }

     void doSomething() {
          // Access some internal state which is hard to mock
     }
}
```

You can deal with this by just overriding that in your test.

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod () {
    Me fixture = new Me() {
       @Override
       void doSomething() { 
       }
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(7, fixture.myMethod());
}
```

Using [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) you can achieve the same with `spy` and `doAnswer`.  For example.

```
    Me me = new Me(); // the original fixture

    Me mySpy = spy(me); // a spied version when you can copy the behaviour
    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock inv) throws Throwable {
            throw new Exception("Hello!");
        }
    }).when(mySpy).doSomething();

    // Will throw an exception or obviously whatever you put in the body of the answer method
    mySpy.doSomething();
```

Comment: This would be like adding a "dummy" implementation, right?  I'm not going into that direction when you have mocking APIs to do it for me.  That's the whole point of their existence.

Comment: @Paul, But there is no point using a library which would be more complex to describe the implementation than using plain Java.

Comment: I've added an example using Mockito.  It's significantly more complicated (the InvocationOnMock object gives you the arguments as an untyped array) but I guess it does it for you to some extent.

Comment: @Peter i don't think it will make it more complex.  Of course it depends on the API to use.  That's part of the objective of this question.  If it does make it more complex, then the API will not be worth it.

Comment: thank you for providing the Mockito example. This is very helpful. I appreciate it. I'm interested on how the scenario is achieved using existing Mocking frameworks. Of course, this can also be done using plain Java @Override. These example is a good basis for comparing my options.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently implemented the mocking of internal methods with EasyMock for a project we were working on. This was implemented following the EasyMock documentation. See section *Partial Mocking* in the [EasyMock documentation](http://www.easymock.org/EasyMock3_1_Documentation.html).

Here is how I wrote the unit test:

Lets assume that an API `getTopNVideosByTagNameAndProperty` in class `VideoAPI` need to be unit tested and this method internally calls another public method in the same class `getVideosByTagName`. The internal method takes in a parameter and returns a List. The method `getVideosByTagName` has to be mocked with EasyMock's mock builder.

**CODE**:

```
//create the mock object with the help of Mock Builder and then add the method to be mocked.    
VideoAPI videoApi=EasyMock.createMockBuilder(Video.class).addMockedMethod("getVideosByTagName").createMock();

String tagName ="sometag"; // create the paramter
// create a dummy return object you expect from the internal method getVideosByTagName
List listVideos = new ArrayList();      
for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++) { //populate listVideos }

//set up the EasyMock for the mocked method call
EasyMock.expect(videoApi.getVideosByTagName(tagName)).andReturn(listVideos).anyTimes();
EasyMock.replay(videoApi);

//now call the actual method to be tested - in this case it returns top 5 videos
List<Video> listVideoTopN = videoApi.getTopNVideosByTagNameAndProperty("tag", "likes", 5);

//do the asserts
assertNotNull(listVideoTopN);
assertEquals(5, listVideoTopN.size());
//finally verify the mocks
EasyMock.verify(videoApi);
```

This is working perfectly fine for me.